# I Need API Scan Date Month Year Sign Up For Facebook Account From UID

Tags: api, facebook

I Need API Scan Date Month Year Sign Up For Facebook Account From UID.
I Need API Scan Date Month Year Sign Up For Facebook Account From UID
I Need API Scan Date Month Year Sign Up For Facebook Account From UID

Comment: why are you repeating your question in a detailed section 3 times? you should describe your question in a detailed section please go through this link once. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need facebook developer account

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/{your-user-id}
?fields=birthday,email
&access_token={your-user-access-token}"
```

[Read the documentations](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/)